# How testing the Pig Scripts

Tags: apache-pig

```
I am new to Hadoop i need to testing the pig scripts could you please tell how to testing the pig scripts in pigunit testing.
```

I try the following cmds.

> **ant jar pigunit-jar** from Pig home path

It doesn't give any jar file to make testing the pig scripts.

I can't understand this above procedure, please explain elaborate

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To compile PigUnit run the command shown below from the Pig trunk. The compile will create the pigunit.jar file.

```
$pig_trunk ant pigunit-jar
```

You can refer the [PigUnit documentation](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/test.html#pigunit) here.